# Test FastAPI OAuth2PasswordRequestForm Got 400 status code

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, pytest, fastapi

I am trying to test a route that will check user credentials.

Here is my **unit test**

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "payload, status_code",
    [
        [{"username": "john", "password": "secret"}, status.HTTP_200_OK],
        [{"username": "john"}, status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED],
        [{"password": "secret"}, status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED],
        [{}, status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED]
    ]
)
def test_user_credentials(test_app: TestClient, monkeypatch, payload, status_code):
    async def mock_check_credentials(credentials:User):
        if "email" in payload and "password" in payload:
            return True
        return False

    monkeypatch.setattr(user_repository, "check_credentials", mock_check_credentials)
    response = test_app.post("/users/credentials", data=json.dumps(payload),  headers={"content-type": "multipart/form-data"})
    assert response.status_code == status_code
```

And here is my **route**

```py
@router.post("/credentials", status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def check_user_credentials(request: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
    valid_credentials = await user_repository.check_credentials(request)
    if not valid_credentials:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect username or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
    return True
```

Here is my **repository method**:

```py
async def check_credentials(user: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm):
    query = Users.select().where(Users.c.email == user.username)
    exists = await database.fetch_one(query=query)
    if not exists:
        return False
    password_ok = hashing.verify(exists.get("password"), user.password)
    if not password_ok:
        return False
    return True
```

But I got status code 400 where I expect or 200 for the first test or 401 for the others tests.

```py
test_app = <starlette.testclient.TestClient object at 0x7f75199fb9a0>, monkeypatch = <_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch object at 0x7f7519c369a0>, payload = {}, status_code = 401

    @pytest.mark.parametrize(
        "payload, status_code",
        [
            [{"username": "john", "password": "secret"}, status.HTTP_200_OK],
            [{"username": "john"}, status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED],
            [{"password": "secret"}, status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED],
            [{}, status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED]
        ]
    )
    def test_user_credentials(test_app: TestClient, monkeypatch, payload, status_code):
        async def mock_check_credentials(credentials:User):
            if "email" in payload and "password" in payload:
                return True
            return False
    
        monkeypatch.setattr(user_repository, "check_credentials", mock_check_credentials)
        response = test_app.post("/users/credentials", data=json.dumps(payload),  headers={"content-type": "multipart/form-data"})
>       assert response.status_code == status_code
E       assert 400 == 401
E        +  where 400 = <Response [400]>.status_code

tests/test_user.py:75: AssertionError
==================================================================================================================================================================================================== short test summary info =====================================================================================================================================================================================================
FAILED tests/test_user.py::test_user_credentials[payload0-200] - assert 400 == 200
FAILED tests/test_user.py::test_user_credentials[payload1-401] - assert 400 == 401
FAILED tests/test_user.py::test_user_credentials[payload2-401] - assert 400 == 401
FAILED tests/test_user.py::test_user_credentials[payload3-401] - assert 400 == 401
================================================================================================================================================================================================== 4 failed, 8 passed in 0.58s ===================================================================================================================================================================================================
ERROR: 1
```

In manual test (with Swagger UI) this route works perfectly.

I cannot face out what I am missing here

EDIT : I found [this thread](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1673) but it did not helped me : I have `python-multipart>=0.0.5` in my requirement.txt ans I have installed it

Comment: Damn exactly same thing happened to me ....

Comment: @PrzemysławSamsel : I thought that I was alone...haha. Sorry but did not found any solution yet

Comment: No worries. Some research though revealed that this /credentials endpoint needs form data in a form of "url-encoded/multiform". I googled it and the only thing I found was using  ```data = {"username" : username, "password" : password} ``` and then I retrieved bearer token using ```response = client.post("/token", data=data)``` (I am using ```TestClient``` class from fastAPI for testing purpose). As your code is pretty similar to mine, I have a feeling it originates from the same fastAPI docs page so maybe this will help you or someone else

Comment: Did you find any solution on this ?

Comment: @StavrosAnastasiadis : no...sorry

Comment: Make no sense! This, for example, https://github.com/rochacbruno/fastapi-project-template/blob/main/tests/conftest.py#L56 . More or less is the same and works in test case. Its the kind of issues I refer as "darkness".

Comment: After changing the headers to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" it worked in my case. The find is after trying to debug and got to this, https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/master/starlette/requests.py#L244 line.  Hope that helps.